# Renegade Category Defies LowSeg2Cat

Tags: low-seg2cat

I am running EE 2.10.1 and LowSeg2Cat 2.8.1/3.0. On this [page](http://rouviere.com/photo/category/ming-tombs) more than 20 photos from the Ming Tomb category should be showing, however, only one appears.

This is the only category [of many](http://rouviere.com/photo/) that does this. The other category images all display fine.

```
{exp:channel:entries  channel="photos" limit="20" category="{segment_3_category_id}" disable="trackbacks" pagination="bottom"}
<div class="photo_thumb">
<a href="{site_url}photo/image/{url_title}/{segment_3}">
<img class="preview {if photo_orientation == 'vert'} vert{/if}" src="/resources/stock/{photo_name}-tn.jpg" data-fullimg="/resources/stock/{photo_name}-preview.jpg" data-caption="{exp:char_limit total="40"}{photo_caption}{/exp:char_limit}" alt="{title}" />
</a>
</div><!-- end photo_thumb -->

{paginate}
{if "{total_pages}" != 1}
<p id="pages">Page {current_page} of {total_pages}  {pagination_links}</p>
{/if}
{/paginate}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Any clues as to why this is not working correctly along with a solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have stumbled upon one of the classics in debugging ExpressionEngine. A still common gotcha that even seasoned veterans get bitten by every now and then. A property that makes us wonder: why is this still default behaviour? But why wonder...

Try `dynamic="no"`.

Comment: Brilliant answer - not only did it solve the problem, but it was a joy to read. thank you!